# Migrating a question which is already posted on the other site

Tags: discussion

When a question begins by saying "This question appeared earlier on math.stackexchange.com" and links to that earlier posting, how does it make sense to migrate it to math.stackexchange.com (thereby creating a duplicate question on that site)?

Comment: I see that at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459198/tangent-half-angles-and-linear-fractional-transformations you used the word "imbecile" to describe the people who migrated your question.  Given what you seem to think of the people who migrated your question, it's not clear what the point of this question is.

Comment: Okay, the dollar sign trick in the title there actually annoyed me. The title renders in lots of places without MathJax, and if you can't be bothered crafting a descriptive title, I doubt I'm interested in the rest.

Comment: I'm sorry that my haste caused me to choose the word "imbecile".  I should have said: This instance of migration looks as if whoever did it was paying no attention to what they were doing, since it is absurd to move a post to m.s.e. when it's already there, and it actually began with a statement saying it's already there.

Answer (score 8):

Here is one way it makes sense: Migration makes it possible to close the question as a duplicate.

Of course, I don't really see why that would be necessary when "off-topic" or "unclear" are often good alternatives.

**Edit:** Okay, the reason I constructed was a little far-fetched.  Here's another way such an event might reasonably take place.  Someone might click on the wrong option when choosing a reason for closing.

Here's a third way it might make sense.  Some of the people voting to close a question might not read every sentence thoroughly, especially if a given sentence doesn't look very mathematical or looks like pointless noise.  Instead, they may decide only on the basis of the mathematical content of the question that while not appropriate for MathOverflow, it may find a good home at math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: To be more precise than the word "imbecile": it appeared that whoever migrated it was not attentive to what he or she was doing, since it makes no sense to move it back there when it's already there.  If it ought to be closed, is there some reason why closing it as a duplicate on m.s.e. is preferable to closing it on m.o.?

Comment: I find the first reason you gave reasonable, by contrast the clicked wrong-option seems very unlikely to me, as while this certainly happened for some reasons, for migration there is the additional step of choosing a target site, so at least at that point one should note the error.

Answer (score 4):

This is one comment on the question

> I gave a partial answer on MSE, and I think the question should remain there. Voting to close here. – Todd Trimble

Now I do not know if Todd Trimble specifically voted to migrate or something else, but in any case it seems clear that at least some (and I see not reason to assume why not all) were aware of the situation.

IIRC, it was mentioned some time ago by a moderator here that they agreeed with a/the moderator(s) there (I believe it was Scott Morrison who said it and the m.SE mod that got mentioned was Willie Wong, but I might misremeber) that for "bad" cross-posts a reasonable procedure could be *to migrate and then close as duplicate*.

This question does not fall directly in the "bad" cross-post vategory as you provided a link youself, still I think by extrapolation it makes sense to proceed like this or at least to assume it makes sense to proceed like this.

Also, if the question is not on-topic here but is on math.SE then it should be migrated (or at least can be), whether it is a duplicate there is a priori not relevant. If one would start to take this consideration into account things would get complicated (what if I knew something will be a duplicate on m.SE, but not in such an obvious form?).

Finally, there are practical considerations: like

- a migration-stub gets always auto-deleted for closed questions auto-deletion only happens under certain circumstances;
- it makes a difference for latter (semi-)automatic maintance if something is actually closed as a duplicated or just closed differently and the text explains it.
- closure as off-topic casts a downvote, migration does not (AFAIK, except it gets rejected on target site, but dup closure is not rejection). 
  So, migration saved you from a down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion, which could serve to alleviate the concerns described here.

1. When there has been a vote to migrate, the OP is informed of the decision, and is asked to give consent. If consent is not given, the question automatically goes "on hold" as "off topic".
2. Once the OP has given consent, the question is moved to the review queue of the site being migrated to. If users there agree for the question to be migrated, it is migrated. Otherwise, it remains in MO as "off topic".

Given the concerns raised above, what do others make of this feature request?

Comment: In this case just some explanation would have helped.  It looked as if someone was putting the question where it already was and ignoring the opening statement that it was already there.

Comment: re 2: This seems almost as it is now. People on the target site can close the question (as any other question). If it is closed on target site (except for duplicate-closure), it becomes off-topic closed on source site. Depending on what you mean precisely by 'move to the review queue' it is still closer. (What I mean for allmost all the review queues the post is anyway already on the site while being "under review"; an exception, and I think the only one is 'approved edits'). So, this seems like a complication for little gain.

Comment: re 1: I can imagine why somebody thinks this would be better, I however feel that first this does not warrant the complication (and I am yet to await a moderately convincing argument why there is that much issue with the "repost" [I think meanwhile we have agreement one can see it like this] for which we have permssion [also here it seems in the end there was agreement with this], albeit not explicit approval; both the wallet and the journal analogy given are non-analogies). Second, did anybody actually complain based on reasons somewhat along the 'ethical problems' line (M.H. not, it seems)

Comment: Third, it sends the completely wrong message. In my opinion, people already think way to much in terms of their questions and their answers. It would be more in line, in my opinion, with the spirit of the site, if people would think more of post they contributed (as opposed to their posts). While I am not active on Wikipedia, I still think it could be helpful to think of making a contribution there as the closer analogous activity to posting something here (as opposed to writing a paper; although this is really not the only problem with the journal analogy).

Comment: @MichaelHardy What was not sufficient about the comment I quoted? Clearly the person making it was aware of the question already being on math.SE. (It is reasonable you might have missed it, but still it was made.)

Comment: Daniel's suggestion is very good! @quid: As usual too many letters and symbols like "[,]"in your answer prevents me from reading it to the end. Can you try being more laconic? What's your point?

Comment: @MarkSapir: then don't. you can then reask it to get the same information from somebody else.

Answer (score -5):

I have expressed my opinion before and I reiterate here. Migrating to math SE (or anywhere else) is not ethically correct. We can only decide that the question is bad for MO, not that it is "more appropriate" for another site. As for math SE, from what I heard, it is populated by undergraduate students trying to cheat by posting their homework questions, and by mathematicians helping the cheating. Perhaps I am wrong, but if I am correct, migrating a question there would be even more wrong.

**Edit**  For those who still do not understand why it is wrong: suppose that you submit  a paper to Annals of Mathematics, and the editorial board there send it to Mathematische Annalen - without your approval and without even notifying you.

Comment: First, perhaps you could elaborate on why, in your opinion, it is not ethically correct instead of just repeating it. Second, perhaps you could have a look yourself to form an opinion instead of just going by hearsay. Finally, and perhaps most importantly, since in this particular, and the abstract situation to be discussed here, the **question was/is already on math.SE** it is completely unclear to me how there could be any ethical problem in sending a *second* copy there; whether or not this is reasonable seems like a purely practical/adminsitrative question.

Comment: @quid: 1. I explained (twice) that it is ethically wrong because we cannot be sure that the question is good for any other site than MO. It would be ethically correct to first ask the OP whether he/she/it wants to migrate the question or suggest to migrate it (as it was on the previous version of MO).

Comment: 2. Sending a copy of a question to anywhere without asking OP's approval is obviously ethically wrong. The question does not belong to the people who migrate it, it belongs to the OP. Is that clear? To be more clear, suppose you have a wallet and I (and 4 others) decide that it is more appropriate that X has it. Would you agree that your wallet was "migrated" to X?

Comment: re 1: why can't "we be sure" I can see why some feel uncomfortable to decide something is good for math.SE when they do not know that site, but others know *that site very well* so I do not see why those cannot decide this. re 2: via posting here everybody licenses the content under CC; this even constitutes agreeing to the content being reproduced *wherever* and *without the need for consent* provided the source is mentioned. By contrast I never agreed to anything like this regarding my wallet (in addition to my wallet not being reproduced here, but I would loose it, which is not true here).

Comment: But if you'd want to create a "copy" of my wallet, I might agree to this. [Except you'd engage in ethically problematic activity in the process like 'copying' money :-)] Furthermore, there are even some journals that ask the referees in addition to accept/reject to possibly suggest a more appropriate journal (by the same publisher). So it is not that unusual that competent people voice their opinion regarding more appropriate venues for dissemination. Sure in this case the authors then needs to agree, but again here auth. would loose possibility to publish elsewhere, not the case here.

Comment: @quid: How do I (or the OP) know that these people know the other Web site? How does the system know that a person who voted to migrate is an expert in math SE? With 25K of reps, I can vote to migrate too. And even if these people are experts, they have no right to take a question that does not belong to them and move it to another Web site. I think that the MO community can close a question, delete a question, suspend the OP (say, for spam), even call the OP "imbecile", but cannot "migrate" OP's question.

Comment: One cannot know if the people making decisions are competent. But neither can one really know this for any other decision; I can vote to close on each question on MO but not for all am I competent to do so; this does not mean that every vote I cast is ethically problematic (while I would consider it as problematic if I would vote on certain questions were I am incompetent). if I do/did not feel competent for a given question than I did not vote; same for migration.  *But* if there should be many problems with "wrong" migrations then the migration path could and likely will be closed. [cont.]

Comment: And then only mods (possibly after consultation with the other sites mods) can migrate. But so far the rate of error is low, more than 95% of questions were not rejected on math.SE (which they could via closing them) then we'd get it back. In addition, 'migration' means closing it here (technically it is locked but this is not so very different) and *posting a copy there*. Why should somebody not be allowed to decide to post a copy of somebodies question elsewhere, when they in fact got explicit permission to do so from OP (they agreed in advance via posting here).

Comment: @quid: You still do not understand the difference between closing (the community thinks that the question is not appropriate in that community) and migrating (the community think that the question should belong to some other community). The former can be done without OP's approval because the OP submitted the question to that community, and the latter cannot be done without OP's approval (because the OP did not submit the question to the other site). I do not think it is worth continuing the discussion until you realize the difference.

Comment: Okay, we can stop the discussion, but I will allow myself to reiterate this point: The OP in fact always **has given permission** (in advance) to the content being reproduced elsewhere (via publishing their content under a CC license, CC-BY-SA 3.0, I think, to be precise; see the bottom of the page for details).

Comment: @MarkSapir : Your statement that "it is populated by undergraduate students trying to cheat by posting their homework questions, and by mathematicians helping the cheating." shows you are not exprerienced with m.s.e.  That probably happens, but that is not most of what is posted.  Some questions are obviously from graduate students or from mathematicians.  How about [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447563/ordinary-and-polar-vector-fields-in-euclidean-3-space) or.....

Comment: ...or  [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448967/illustrative-examples-of-a-phenomenon-in-the-logic-of-mathematical-induction) or [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420364/who-is-buried-in-weierstrass-tomb) or [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170803/convergence-of-alternating-series-weakening-a-hypothesis)?

Comment: ....and if you want to see mathematicians complicit in academic cheating, look at those who design a system and a curriculum that predictably has the effect of encouraging millions of students to take calculus without knowing the prerequisite material.  It brings in tuition money and it helps sell textbooks to a captive audience for $200 apiece, which drives up the price of all math books.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: As I said, indeed, I do not know anything about m.s.e. My opinion is formed by what was said on the meta before. This does not make migrating a question there without OP's approval any more appropriate.

Comment: Most is certainly an overstatement.  I'd guesstimate around 20% of the questions on the site are homework questions.

Comment: @NoahSnyder: Which one is an overstatement? 20% of questions homework,  which is tolerated (or even encouraged?) by the community is very bad.

Comment: Various discussions are happening there how to handle homework problems properly; with varying opinions but I think it is fair to say that the mainstream-view is not at all oblivious regarding problems related to this. (In addition just that 20% of the questions are HW does not mean the all get an answer, roughly, the guidleine is for HW  hints only.) And, it is not that different than here. It is not like nobody ever got a solution to a HW problem on MO. (Besides personally I do not even consider it as that relevant, but this is besides the point.)

Comment: The edited in analogy is not very apt unless you change it to "submit to Annals and allow them to send it on wherever they please as long as they make it clear who wrote it" since this is the permission you give when you write something on MO (and MSE).

Comment: Mark Sapir has made a non-trivial point which I had not considered before. I will be more careful about voting to migrate questions in the future.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Where exactly do I give this permission?

Comment: That is part of the licence you have agreed to publish under when posting things on MO. Though I cannot seem to find a good reference for it for some reason.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I cannot find it either. Does it exist and what exactly does it say?

Comment: Found it on http://stackexchange.com/legal

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: And where is it in the agreement? The word "migrate" is not there. Also that agreement existed before this Summer also?

Comment: @StefanKohl: Where in that agreement is it written, that migrating a question is legally allowed?

Comment: I have made a separate question about it. There is an answer there but I am not sure it it correct. Also "legally possible" does not mean "morally possible", and I think that regardless of legal issues, migrating a question without OP's consent is not ethically correct (unlike closing and deleting).

Comment: The separate question mentioned in the comment above is at http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/583/12357

Comment: @MarkSapir : I don't think 20% homework means 20% cheating.  Students ought to ask more questions than they do about homework.

Comment: ....and anyone concerned about cheating should be concerned about institutionalized cheating of kinds that is FAR worse than all those teachers in Atlanta getting arrested for falsifying answers to standardized tests.

Comment: @MichaelHardy:  Asking questions and getting answers is a part of a teaching process. Students should try to use the stuff in their heads (assuming that it is not just fluff) and work on the homework problems on their own. Asking your teacher for help is usually allowed (except for the tests). Asking MO, m.s.e., etc. for help,  is cheating for obvious reasons.  It should result in automatic "F", and a letter to the University Honors committee which, in turn, brings a lot of trouble. Justifying somebody's cheating by somebody else's cheating is useless.

Comment: @MarkSapir: you say "Asking MO, m.s.e., etc. for help, is cheating for obvious reasons" this is obviously false in this generality.

Comment: @quid: It is true. I was talking about help with homework and tests.

Comment: @MarkSapir my students can get the solutions to their homework in whathever way they like. They only *then* need to understand it. So it is false.

Comment: @quid: Yes, I should have written "Asking help ... without teacher's approval ...". If the teacher approves asking for help on m.s.e. or MO or elsewhere (which can of course happen), that should be included in the question.

Comment: With this modification in place, we agree.

Comment: re the journal-analogy I'd like to add more details to what I said before it even came up, namely that things not unlike this *actually* happen: "3. Transfer. Papers that are of high quality but are inappropriate for SIAP can be transferred to another SIAM journal for consideration. Both EICs involved and the author(s) must approve the transfer. The EICs must agree before the author(s) is consulted. If the author agrees to the transfer, the original paper is marked rejected (RJ) and a new file is opened with a different manuscript number." source: http://www.siam.org/journals/siap/review.php

Comment: Comment: It is true that here the author also must agree in the end, **but** according to the description the respective Editors in Chief decide *before* the author is consulted about the idea. (And, of course here author's agreement is a lot more relevant as typicallly one can only ever publish a paper once, unlike asking some question somewhere.) But that the paper is sent by one editorail board to another without the author being asked can happen. (Sorry for coming back to this, but not having said this makes me nervous.)

Comment: The principal form of cheating in math courses is treating the learning of material as a price paid to get a grade, rather than as the thing they're there for.  The obvious solution is to make grades in courses at most an off-the-record private communication from the teacher to the student.